# 401 unauthorized after changing master page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, master-page

I receive a "401 unauthorized" on `http://mysite/_layouts/15/...` after changing the default master page `seattle.master` to a custom master page. I am using the following PowerShell script:

```
$site_url = "http://mysite/"

$site = Get-SPSite $site_url
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    $web.MasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl +  "_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master";
    $web.CustomMasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master";
    $web.Update();
    Write-Host $web.Url $web.MasterUrl $web.CustomMasterUrl;
}
```

All subsites and other site collections still seem to work.

The problem seems to be the difference between: `http://mysite` (working) and `http://mysite/` (extra slash: not working). All links are linking to `http://mysite/` (with slash). How to fix this?

Comment: Could you add how you define the `$site_url`?

Comment: @moe See updated question

Comment: Everything seems to be just fine as long as you use the URL as `"/_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master";` (note the `/` at the begin). On a side note, not sure how your environment is set up, but you might have to apply the masterpage change to whole web application as it's possible to build My Sites so that each person's site is actually a site collection of its own. Confirm your hierarchy on Central Administration.

Comment: @moe I get this error with the slash: 'http://mysite/search /_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master /_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master'
Exception setting "MasterUrl": ""//_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master" contains invalid character '/'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your usage of `ServerRelativeUrl`.

`ServerRelativeUrl` always starts with `/` and ends with the rest of the URL to the site. For instance, server-relative URL of http://server/sites/site01 is /sites/site01 (no ending `/`).

However, in the case of a root site collection (i.e. http://server), the server-relative URL is simply `/`: it starts and ends with the same `/`...

The easy solution is to trim ending `/`, or to use a method such as [`SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.spurlutility.combineurl.aspx) that will take care of such problems:

```
$site_url = "http://mysite/"

$site = Get-SPSite $site_url
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    $web.MasterUrl = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility]::CombineUrl($site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, "_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master");
    $web.CustomMasterUrl = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility]::CombineUrl($site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, "_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master");
    $web.Update();
    Write-Host $web.Url $web.MasterUrl $web.CustomMasterUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$site_url` is defined correctly, add `/`'s to your `MasterUrl` and `CustomMasterUrl` as following:

```
$site = Get-SPSite $site_url
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    $web.MasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl +  "/_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master";
    $web.CustomMasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master";
    $web.Update();
    Write-Host $web.Url $web.MasterUrl $web.CustomMasterUrl;
}
```